# What is the area of the polygon fromed by the points (x,y) which satisfy the inequality: $ |x| + \frac{|y|}{2} \leq 1$

Tags: absolute-value

I have an SAT II question that asks: What is the area of the polygon formed by the points (x,y) which satisfy the inequality:
$ |x| + \frac{|y|}{2} \leq 1$

a) 2    b) 3  c) 4   d) 8  e) 10

How would you go about solving this?

Comment: Try drawing the region described by $\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert /2 \le 1$. It should break up nicely into smaller sub-regions of which you can easily calculate the area.

Answer (score 1):

The shape above will have twice the area of the points that satisfy
$|x|+|y| \le 1$ which is four times the area of the points that satisfy
$x+y \le 1$ and $x,y \ge 0$. The latter is easily seen to be ${ 1\over 2}$
hence the answer is $4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Divide your graph into quadrants. In each one, draw the region formed. e.g., in the top right hand quadrant you have the half plane $x+y/2\le1$, in the lower left quadrant you have $-x -y/2 \le 1$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

$$|x| + \frac{|y|}{2} \leq 1$$

This is a taxicab geometry ellipse or, better yet, a rhombus. The coordinates of the vertices are 
$(0,\pm 2), (\pm 1, 0)$.

The lengths of its diagonals are $D = 2-(-2) = 4$ and $d=1-(-1) = 2$

Notice that the diagonals break up the rhombus into four congruent right triangles with sides of $\frac 12D$ and $\frac 12d$ and area of $\frac 18dD$.

So the area of the rhombus is $4(\frac 18dD) = \frac 12 dD = 4$